# How to get Three DIV element in one row?

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to be able to get the third "promobox" to come up to the first row with the other two, it just goes onto the next row but it is set to a percentage so it shouldn't matter.
I have tried to fix this with an answer from another forum but I simply can't do it.
Help would be great.
Thanks heaps.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;
    }

#container {
    width: 100%; height: 500px;
    max-width: 1440px; min-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
    }

.bigbox {
    height: 530px;
    background-image: url(images/photos/landscape-1440.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border: 2px solid red;
    }

.promobox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

.promobox div {
    height: 200px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    border-style: none;
    }


div {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }

div a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

#pb1 {width: 25%;} 


#pb2 {width: 50%;}

#pb3 {width: 25%}




</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

    <div id="container">
<div class="bigbox">

<div class="promobox" id="pb1">#</div>
<div class="promobox" id="pb2">#</div>
<div class="promobox" id="pb3">#</div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Don't mix up `px` and `%` while specifying width. Either use `%` everywhere or use `px`. Using fixed length i.e. `px` results best in this case.

Comment: Another Trick : If you are using `%`, calculate the sum of the width in a way so that it becomes `< 100%`. Say, set the width of your 3 DIV like ` 24% 50% 24% `. You will see the exact result you want.

Comment: In your HTML you have empty space in between div, it generates a white-space once you display your div as inline-block. 25%+50%+25% + 2 white-space +borders  is more than 100% . borders can be included using box-sizing, and white-space erased from HTML with comment or via CSS setteing font-size to 0 and back to 16px or so for promobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **two** things that could mess the 3 boxes getting aligned next to each other.
The given `border:2px solid green;` and the `display: inline-block;`

You cant have the boxes have a total of 100% when using border.. because the borders need to be a part of the 100%.

```
.promobox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    float:left;         /*Change the display:inline-block to this */
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AuCr4/)** *(without the borders)*

Comment: box-sizing may allow you to keep the borders :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for the border of the divs thus you're going over the 100% width. The simplest solution would be either removing the border or having the total width less than or equals to 98%

e.g.

```
#pb1 {width: 24%;} 
#pb2 {width: 50%;}
#pb3 {width: 24%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly i make an answser of my comment : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fGmjC/) with the fix below**

---

In your `HTML` you have empty space in between div, it generates a `white-space` once you `display` your div as `inline-block`.

25%+50%+25% + 2 `white-space` +`borders` is more than 100% .

borders can be included using `box-sizing`, and `white-space` erased from HTML with `<!--comment-->` or via CSS setting `font-size` to 0 and back to 16px or so for `.promobox`.

---

Update for your CSS:

---

```
.bigbox {
  font-size:0;
    } 
.promobox {
  box-sizing:border-box;/* add vendor prefix where needed */
  font-size:16px;/* fallback*/
  font-size:1rem;
    }
```

Comment: `Border`s could be dropped and drawn from an `inset` `box-shadow`  `box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px green;` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tEfpd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;
    }

#container {
    width: 100%; height: 500px;
    max-width: 1440px; min-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

.bigbox {
    height: 530px;
    background-image: url(images/photos/landscape-1440.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

.promobox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float:left;
    }

.promobox div {
    height: 200px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    border-style: none;
    }


div {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }

div a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

#pb1 {width: 25%;} 


#pb2 {width: 50%;}

#pb3 {width: 25%}




</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

    <div id="container">
<div class="bigbox">

<div style='background:red' class="promobox" id="pb1">#</div>
<div style='background:green' class="promobox" id="pb2">#</div>
<div style='background:yellow' class="promobox" id="pb3">#</div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Remove background when you implement it. :)

Comment: try too to explain that float do not generate white-spaceand why you removed the borders :))

Comment: because border effects the div width . You can use border but then you have to decrease div with with pixels used for borders.

Comment: I meant in your answer to make it more valuable :) , you only posted a piece of code

Answer (score -1):

here's a working demo of two divs in a row

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block;">Div 1</div>
<div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;">Div 2</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/MZrym/)

Comment: You should give a working answer, using the code of the OP. Not just an example of 2 divs in a row..